# When using bootstrap Radio without preselecting an option, the first option result checked even if nothing is

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use [Bootstrap Radio](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) using the following markup and js

```
<div class="form-control type">
    <div class="radio-header">Please select the type of gallery item you want to create</div>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" div_class="form-inline" class="visibility_switcher" id="type_image_0" value="image" name="dgt_gallery_item[0][type]" />Image</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" div_class="form-inline" class="visibility_switcher" id="type_quote_0" value="quote" name="dgt_gallery_item[0][type]" />Quote</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" div_class="form-inline" class="visibility_switcher" id="type_text_0" value="text" name="dgt_gallery_item[0][type]" />Text</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" div_class="form-inline" class="visibility_switcher" id="type_video_0" value="video" name="dgt_gallery_item[0][type]" />Video</label>
    </div>
</div>

    $( '#gallery_items .admin-card' ).each( function( index, element ) {
        var name = $( 'input:radio:first', this ).attr( 'name' );
        var type = $(' input[name="' + name + '"]:checked',this ).val();
        switch_visibility_of_gallery_fields_by_type( type, this );
    } );
```

`.admin-card` is a parnet field that contains many form inputs.
As you see no option is preselected in html, but in jQuery, on firefox, the first radio results checked. This is also true in bootstrap as selecting the first option doesn't trigger the "change" event. This works as expected in chrome 64 Windows.
Any idea on what to use on firefox?I need to get the value of the first checked radio or undefined if no radio is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firefox persists form control states (disabledness and checkedness)
>   across page loads. A workaround for this is to use autocomplete="off".

Try adding `autocomplete="off"` for the input fields.

```
<input type="radio" div_class="form-inline" class="visibility_switcher" id="type_image_0" value="image" name="dgt_gallery_item[0][type]" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Great, i was wondering if that was the cause, and now i also know why!